# std::vector push_back() erases previous element

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a class "terrain" (every single special function is defined - I'm desperate)

So, when i define objects one by one, everything works fine, but it's ineffective when it comes to multiple objects. So i made a std::vector of my terrain.

```
std::vector<terrain> defined_terrains;
```

Everything looks fine, I have a function that prints all content of objects.
So I do:

```
defined_terrains.push_back({args...})
defined_terrains[0].print_data();
```

The above code works like this:

```
  /// push_back starts 
COPY CSTR: object test 1
DSTR: object test 1
  /// push_back finishes

  /// print_data starts
Data:
name: object test 1
id: 1003
hitbox:
{
-0.0520833
-0.078125

-0.0520833
0.078125

0.0520833
0.078125

0.0520833
-0.078125

}

frames:
{
-0.0520833
-0.078125

-0.0520833
0.078125

0.0520833
0.078125

0.0520833
-0.078125

}

RGB:
{
0.392157
0.784314
0.196078

}
offset:
x: 0.104167
y: -0.3125
on ground: no
fall time: 0
direction 1
destructible: 0
transparent: 0
grounding:
 left limit: 0
 right limit: 0
blocked from above: 0
  /// print_data finishes
```

Everything is perfect. But then i add next element to std::vector:

```
defined_terrains.push_back({args...})
defined_terrains[1].print_data();
```

This happens:

```
*everything the same for object test 1*

  /// push_back starts 
COPY CSTR: object test 2
COPY CSTR: object test 1  <----- why does this happen? defined_terrains[0] was not involved here
DSTR: object test 1 <----------- its like defined_terrains[1] used defined_terrains[0] like temporary (???)
DSTR: object test 2
  /// push_back finishes 

  /// print_data starts
name: object test 2
id: 1004
hitbox:
{
-0.0520833
-0.078125

-0.0520833
0.078125

0.0520833
0.078125

0.0520833
-0.078125

}

frames:
{
-0.0520833
-0.078125

-0.0520833
0.078125

0.0520833
0.078125

0.0520833
-0.078125

}

RGB:
{
0.392157
0.784314
0.196078

}
offset:
x: -0.104167
y: -0.390625
on ground: no
fall time: 0
direction 1
destructible: 0
transparent: 0
grounding:
 left limit: 0
 right limit: 0
blocked from above: 0
  /// print_data finishes
```

Am I stupid or something? Or is there a serious bug with push_back()?

Comment: Key word: reallocation.

Comment: Reduce your code to the minimum, so that the error can be reproduced. No one wants to read the whole source code :(

Comment: And another: reserve(size_t)

Comment: there is no much reading. You can omit what print_data writes. It's just to check validity of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector is reallocating its storage, so it is basically allocating a new array, copying over the current contents (thus the call to the copy ctor of object 1), storing the new value at the end and releasing the old storage array (thus the destructor invocations for the contents). If your debug printouts showed the address of the object being constructed/destroyed you would see that they are in different places.